# Write a function which computes the perfect sums in an array?

Tags: java, algorithm

Perfect sums is the sum of two or more number of elements of arrays whose sum is equal to a given number. Return 999 if not found.

my method signature is:

```
public static int persfectSum(int arr[], int input)
```

For example:

```
arr={2,3,5,6,8,10}
input = 10;

5+2+3= 10
2+8 = 10
So, the output is 2;
```

Comment: Sounds like homework to me, with no indication of effort. What have you tried so far? Which bit are you stuck on?

Comment: It is the Subset Sum Problem, which is NP Complete

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - you are the savior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is a variation of [Subset-Sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)** - with an additional constraint on the size of the subset (larger then 1).

The problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), but for relatively small integers can be solved using [Dynamic Programming in pseudo-polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem#Pseudo-polynomial_time_dynamic_programming_solution).

A possibly simpler alternative which is feasible for small arrays is brute-force - just search all possible subsets, and verify for each if it matches the sum.

I believe these guidelines are more then enough as a starter for you to start programming the problem and solve your problem (HW?) on your own.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
int PerfectSums(int n, int a[], int sum)
{

    int dp[n + 1][sum + 1] ;
    dp[0][0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
        dp[0][i] = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        dp[i][0] = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= sum; j++)
        {

            if (a[i - 1] > j)
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j];

            else
            {
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j] + dp[i - 1][j - a[i - 1]];
            }
        }
    }

    return (dp[n][sum] == 0 ? 999 : dp[n][sum] ) ;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).